# Eclipse oxigen c++ windows 10 gdb does not work

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, gdb

I installed for the first time Eclipse oxygen with CDT 9.4.0, under Windows 10, gdb 7.10.1 and it fails with messages

```
<terminated>EclipseProject1.exe [C/C++ Application] 
    <terminated, exit value: 0>C:/cygwin64/bin/gdb.exe (7.10.1)
```

doing nothing. I have seen some similar questions raised in the past, but I did not found an answer that worked for me.

Comment: Check that you have gdb installed in your cygwin. I'll suggest to switch into MSYS2 from cygwin, this is newer and better version of the same. P.S. You can try Code::Blocks instead of Eclipse, Eclipse is a Java IDE not really good for C++, and the vise versa.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Gdb is installed and works. I use it regularly with Netbeans. I was trying to switch to Eclipse as common ide for C++, python and java, but it seems it is not a good idea.